# Span Value Changed Back to Old Value After Successful AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have this one weird situation which I am really confused now. I can't see any solution on the Net yet for this weird issue. I have one AJAX call that will populate the data which generated on the page also by using AJAX (dynamic). Here is my code:

My jQuery Code:

```
$(document).delegate('.edit_tr', 'click', function(){
    var the_id = $(this).attr('id');
}).delegate('.edit_tr', 'keypress', function(e){
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var input_name = $("#input_name_" + the_id ).val();
            if(input_name.length > 0){
                //if I reset the span text and do return false here, the text showed properly on the page
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_update.php",
                    data: data_string,
                    success: function(html){
                        //do the reset of span text
                        $('#name_'+the_id+'').html(input_name);
                        alert('Examining'); //while alert is popped up,text of span is expected as changed
                        //after 'OK' is clicked on the alert, the span text go back to its previous text
                     },
                    error: function(err){
                        //do something
                    }
                });
             }
         }
    });
```

Code in another PHP page which gets called via AJAX. This page displays the data on the page before being manipulated by above code for edit in place.

```
$returned_msg .= '<form id="form1">';

if( $contact_details->exists() ){
    $lists = $contact_details->data();

    foreach( $lists as $list ){
        $returned_msg .= '<tr id = "'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" class="edit_tr">
                            <td style="text-align:center"  class="edit_td">
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" id="cont_detail_id_'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" />
                                <span id="name_'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" class="text_span">'.$list->det_name.'</span>
                                <input type="text" value="'.$list->det_name.'" style="width:120px;height:6px;" class="editbox" id="input_name_'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" />
                                <input type="hidden" value="'.$list->det_name.'" class="editbox" id="hidden_name_'.$list->cont_detail_id.'" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>';
    }

    $returned_msg .= '</form>';

}
```

class `editbox` is not displayed till the `tr` is clicked. I am now totally baffled. Looking forward to get some thought on what could probably causing this. Thank you.

Comment: maybe you are setting the text of span somewhere else?

Comment: nope because I have checked the ID. Plus I can see the value changed at the correct place because I have some time to see the progress while alert takes place.

Comment: Have you posted all relevant js code regarding success callback? Maybe some code is submiting a `form`. Anyway, your posted code is missing some context, how do you call this method? What about HTML markup? If you test it setting any other element HTML, is it reseted too? Etc...

Comment: try to change span to div and id to 'name_examining' and populate value. So you can be sure that no one else changing value of this element

Comment: I'm agree with previous comments. Code is missing. When the `alert()` is displayed the rest of the code is stopped while you don't press OK. Maybe you reset the value after.

Comment: what is `input_name` exactly? really a string? remove the alert, what happens?

Comment: @Debflav I have commented the rest of my code in the `success` callback. So I don't do any value reset after that.

@Alex yes it is string taken from a text field. Basically I want to take the value and put it at the span. When I remove alert, span value just change back to its original text

Comment: @SevStryker changing the `span` to `div` and ID changes did not work for me. Tested.

Comment: @A.Wolff Updated my codes.

Comment: @UserProg Post relevant HTML markup too. Is your 'input' `edit_tr` inside a `form`? What happen if you add `e.preventDefault();` for keypress event if `return` key is pressed?

Comment: @A.Wolff yes my `tr` class `edit_tr` is inside a `form`. `e.preventDefault` does not work for me, the value still change.

Comment: @A.Wolff Codes updated.

Comment: I am thinking the problem is because I display it using AJAX, and try to populate the content after that. Meaning that calling the element that is not yet loaded. But the problem is I can see the span text is updated then changed back to old value.